How are Shudras supposed to perform shraddha?
Namaskaram. Performing shraddha involves feeding brahmanas. A brahmana who strongly follows acharams will not eat in a shudra's home for obvious reasons. How should a shudra get around this issue?
Another question I have is about performing rites for the long deceased. My family has not done proper rituals for the dead for some generations as we are a diaspora commmunity. They have no faith in such rituals. I have faith in those rituals but I am a woman and I wish to perform them in some way. Is there a way to counter this issue?

This is an interesting point. Yes, feeding Brahmanas is indeed prescribed. Also, as you mentioned Brahmanas do not eat in Shudra's house! Solution?

Śūdras are prescribed to perform āmaśraddha i.e. śrāddha with uncooked food.
(strīṇāṁ caiva tu śūdrāṇmāmaśrāddhaṁ praśasyate- Skanda Purāṇa 5.3.76.18a) The later ślokas mention the vidhi in brief. @AmritenduMukhopadhyay

The cooked food (in the home of Śūdras) is not to be given to Brāhmaṇas, that food is to be given to the people of one's own jāti.
